# subtracting two matrices and getting absolute value

Tags: r

```
SNP ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4
var1    0   1   1   2
var2    0   0   2   1
var3    2   1   1   0
```

There are two matrices here, colnames are IDs 1 and IDs 2 and SNP numbers are var1 var 2 etc. Both matrices have same ID and and var. I would like to subtract matrix 1 from matrix two and get absolute value. IDs and vars are added to match the data in matrix.

```
SNP ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4
var1    1   1   0   0
var2    0   1   2   0
var3    1   2   2   1
```

I would like to get third matrix

```
SNP ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4
var1    1   0   1   2
var2    0   1   0   1
var3    1   1   1   1
```

Comment: Do you have matrix or data.frame? Looks like `data.frame`.   `d3 <- d1;
 d3[-1] <- abs(d1[-1]-d2[-1])`

Comment: You should make your example reproducible, it helps us help you. (but akrun as the solution anyway)

Answer (score 2):

You want `abs(m1 - m2)`, where `m1` and `m2` are your matrices created with the following

```
m1 <- matrix(c(0,1,1,2,
               0,0,2,1,
               2,1,1,0), ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)

m2 <- matrix(c(1,1,0,0,
               0,1,2,0,
               1,2,2,1), ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)

rownames(m1) <- rownames(m2) <- paste0('var', seq_len(nrow(m1)))
colnames(m1) <- colnames(m2) <- paste0('ID', seq_len(ncol(m1)))
```

This produces.

```
> abs(m1 - m2)
     ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4
var1   1   0   1   2
var2   0   1   0   1
var3   1   1   1   1
```

If they are data frames with an explicit `SNP` column, you are going to want to drop that column: `abs(df1[, -1] - df2[, -1])`